# How to play svga animation in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui, svga

I need to support iOS14, is there any way to play svga animation using SwiftUI?
Here is my svga url: https://iulia.iwlive.club/ng/ring3d3.svga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by [SwiftySVGAPlayer](https://github.com/svga/SVGAPlayer-iOS)

First, use CocoaPod to install SwiftySVGAPlayer:

```
pod 'SwiftySVGAPlayer'
```

Then, implement `UIViewRepresentable` to make SwiftySVGAPlayer available in SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI 
import SVGAPlayer

struct SVGAPlayerView:UIViewRepresentable
{
    var url:URL
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SVGAPlayer {
        let player = SVGAPlayer()
        let parser = SVGAParser()
        parser.parse(with: url) { videoItem in
            if let item = videoItem {
                player.videoItem = item
                player.startAnimation()
            }
        }
        return player
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SVGAPlayer, context: Context) {
    }
}


struct SVGAPlayerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SVGAPlayerView(url: URL(string: "https://iulia.iwlive.club/ng/ring3d3.svga")!)
    }
}
```